# Error in 'recode()'!Argument 2 must be named

Tags: r, dplyr

```
install.packages("dplyr",dependencies = TRUE)

library(dplyr)
```

I input the code above to hopefully fix the error but it did not work.

This is my code:

```
protestag <- recode(Event..legacy..see.tags.,"'Education'=1;'Executive'=2;'Immigration'=3;'Racial Injustice'=4;'Collective Bargaining'=5;'Civil Rights'=6;'Healthcare'=7;else=NA",as.factor=FALSE)
```

This is the error message:

```
Error in `recode()`:
! Argument 2 must be named.
Backtrace:
 1. dplyr::recode(...)
 2. dplyr:::recode.character(...)
```

I'm new to R and not sure what to do.

Comment: You seem to have quoted all your arguments together and used semicolons for some reason. Get rid of the double quotes and change your semicolons to commas, `recode(Event..legacy..see.tags., 'Education' = 1, 'Executive' = 2, ...`. For more examples see the bottom of the `?recode` help page.

Answer (score 0):

```
protestag <-
  recode(
    Event..legacy..see.tags.,
    `1` = 'Education',
    `2` = 'Executive',
    `3` = 'Immigration',
    `4` = 'Racial Injustice',
    `5` = 'Collective Bargaining',
    `6` = 'Civil Rights',
    `7` = 'Healthcare'
  )
```

Comment: Feel free to upvote/accept my answer ;)